# MyEclipse: Is still worth to use it?

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse

Since 2005 we are using MyEclipse as our standard development tool.
We use it mainly for  for Java applications, but from time to time 
we use it also for Groovy and may be other stuff, like DB navigator, etc.

Our licences should be renewed in a couple of months and I am rethinking
the decision of using it. A nice feature of MyEclipse was the debugger which 
allows us to debug client/server applications. Also the hot deployment was a nice
feature. All this stuff can be done without MyEclipse and comparing the memory footprint
of MyEclipse 7.1 woth Eclipse Ganymede the last one wins for far. 
The licence price doesn't matter.

Then the question is what I do loose not using MyEclipse anymore?

opinions are welcome.

Luis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We used to use MyEclipse but we just stopped doing so over time, and didn't really miss it. We're now on Ganymede EE and find it has everything we need, having now implemented some of the things bundled with MyEclipse. Syntax highlighting across various sources such as .css, .js and .sql is nice to have out-of-the-box. And we've always used the remote debugger built right in - it's pretty neat imo, but I didn't realise there was anything special with MyEclipse in this regard. And of course you can install Eclipse and MyEclipse side-by-side while you try things out.

Comment: Exactly. Similar here for my work. I had been using MyEclipse under company's subscription since I first arrived up until another 3 months or so. I felt MyEclipse to be slower compared to vanilla Eclipse. Moved to Eclipse and never looked back at MyEclipse again. Could not be happier. On Neon 2 now for more than a year or so.

Answer (score 5):

I was using MyEclipse for about 3 years between 2002 and 2005. Currently, the functionality coming with Ganymede is IMHO good enough to live without it

Answer (score 1):

A good JavaScript/HTML/CSS editing support, if that concerns you. It was one of the main reason I shifted to Netbeans, not Eclipse, after a using the IntelliJ for a long period.

Comment: I can confirm that the Netbeans Javascript/HTML/CSS editing is top notch. I find it to be superior to Eclipse in every single way.

Comment: i like Aptana Studio for that, it can also be installed as eclipse plugin(but i prefer standalone version).

Answer (score 1):

MyEclipse 8 allows you to configure away some of the many options to improve startup speeds.

There were many problems with v7, especially to do with proxy internet connections, but these seem to be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I was using BEA's Workshop Studio for awhile and the primary features that I ever really used was to control-click on a JSF/JSP to jump to the source code.  Likewise, I wanted to be able to find all references of a given method and have the result set include JSF/JSP references.  I could never get the latter to work though...possibly a config error.  The JSF WYSIWYG was useful on occasion too.  I let my license lapse and didn't feel like paying again what they were asking ($100 - $800).
So I believe MyEclipse is supposed to provide those features as well for much less, but the JSF/JSP link and search didn't work on my initial install.  So I've reverted back to Eclipse EE, which I don't believe provides any of those features (can anyone confirm this?).  Assuming it doesn't and that I could get it to work in MyEclipse, then MyEclipse would be worth it IMO for just those basic features alone.

Answer (score 0):

I was also a big fan for some years, but I realized that when Eclipse has a bug, then also MyEclipse has the same bug and they wait till Eclipse fix it.

So .. why should I pay for MyEclipse? IntelliJ is much stable and cheaper in the third year.

I tried now MyEclipse under Fedora and it's not better - GUI errors, so I  can not work with. Much worser than under Ubuntu :(

Answer (score -2):

Netbeans for PHP is the best. It has database support as well, i.e. you can test your sql queries within the netbeans and see the results. I have been using it for quite sometime and found no problems... Give it a try when you are looking for a change.

Comment: The question is about myEclipse or not myEclipse!

Comment: Please follow the question.